# android upload video and string to server

Tags: php, android, video, upload, httpurlconnection

The code i currently have will uploads a video to the server but I am not sure on how i would a add a string to the server along with the video.
i would like to send the video followed with a string to send to the upload.

```
public String uploadVideo(String file) {

    String fileName = file;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    File sourceFile = new File(file);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
        return null;
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                    .getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }else {
        return "Could not upload";
    }
}
```

Uploadactivity

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Upload u = new Upload();
            String msg = u.uploadVideo(selectedPath);
            return msg;

        }
    }
    UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
    uv.execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
conn.setRequestProperty("stringName", string);
```

after all the `conn.setRequestProperty`'s
then on the server make sure you recive it (on php it's
`$varname = $_POST['stringName'];`

Comment: thank you I would like to send the string through the DoInBackground method do you know i would be able to that to the uploadvideo();